# How can I `initdb` of postgresql in CentOS7.2?

Tags: centos, postgresql

In CentOS 6 I can use `service` for initdb of `postgresql-9.3`:

```
service postgresql-9.3 initdb
```

But, in the CentOS7, I tried bellow, find I can initdb it:

```
# service postgresql-11 initdb
The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop, restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other actions, please try to use systemctl.
[root@www data]# systemctl initdb postgresql-11
Unknown operation 'initdb'.
[root@www data]# systemctl postgresql-11 initdb
Unknown operation 'postgresql-11'.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately You have to use inidb binary directly:

```
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/initdb /var/lib/pgsql/11
```